# Как создать видео-аватар в tableview?

Tags: swift, tableview

Суть: хочу сделать аналог stories в Instagram.
Что пробовал: 
 + Добавлял возможность видео-съемки в приложении.
 + Ложил gif в сell.image.
Получается лажа, если честно.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, куда копать чтобы соорудить аналог stories?
Язык swift. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно зачем вам gif. В Instagram статические иконки историй, при нажатии на которые открывается новый экран с видео. Сделайте так же.
Для иконок историй больше подходит UICollectionView.

Comment: gif я пробовал чтобы посмотрел как оно будет работать в ячейке. т.е. на uiimage положить простой tap и по касанию воспроизводить видео? хм..попробую, спасибо.